# How to create JMS MessageListenerContainer on a list of ConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, spring-jms

The following configuration creates a `MessageListenerContainer` on one `ConnectionFactory`.

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Bean
  public MessageListenerContainer myListenerContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(myConnectionFactory1);
    [...]
    return messageListenerContainer;
  }
}
```

I want to create the same configuration of `MessageListenerContainer` but with differents `ConnectionFactory` (pointing on differents queues managers).

I've tried to return a list of `MessageListenerContainer` (`MessageListenerContainer[]` or `List<MessageListenerContainer>` with or without a `@Qualifier`) but new messages are ignored.

How could I manage the `MessageListenerContainer` creation on a list of `ConnectionFactory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another way to create multiple `MessageListenerContainer`, instead of creating `MessageListenerContainer` you create multiple `JmsListenerContainerFactory` and set the bean name in `JmsListener`.

```
@EnableJms
class JmsConfiguration{

 Bean
 public JmsListenerContainerFactory  jmsListenerContainerFactory(){
     // create jms listener 
 }

 @Bean
 public JmsListenerContainerFactory  jmsListenerContainerFactory2(){
     // create jms listener 
 }

}
```

Two factory beans are created here, `jmsListenerContainerFactory` and `jmsListenerContainerFactory2`, now you can use these factory beans in `JmsListener` to denote which bean to be used.

```
@Component
class JmsListeners {
  @JmsListener(containerFactory="jmsListenerContainerFactory")
  public void onMessage(...){

  }

  @JmsListener(containerFactory="jmsListenerContainerFactory2")
  public void onMessage2(...){

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response.
My JMS Listener is the same for all factories.
My issue is on the creation of MessageListenerContainers or JmsListener. I have a dynamic list of ConnectionFactory, the size of this list can change (dev vs prod env)

Comment: How are you controlling message listener containers based on the profile, FYI you can use only one MessageListener with one container.

Comment: Yes tha't wh'y I want to create severals message listener containers. 
The number of ConnectionFactory (equals to the number of QM) is manage in a configuration file. In dev, I have only one QM, in production: 3...

Comment: can you share some detail about your use case? You can restrict this using the spring profile as well.

Comment: Yes it is a solution to declare differents profiles and to create 1 named bean of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` in dev profile, and 3 in production.

But, I would like to have a more dynamic solution.
My configuration file contains `connection.mq=host1:post1;host2:port2;host3:port3`
and I loop on host/port couples to create connection factories and `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`s

I just do not understand why when I put them in the context, they seems to be inert.

Comment: If you have created N  containers than you can bind only N listeners, so how are you getting to handle in dev since you have 3 listeners and one container. Am I missing something? There's another way, either you can hardcode the containerFactory name but this is not possible since you have dynamic containerFactory, so you can create bean that would provide the containerFactory name.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the beans dynamically with the application context.

```java
@Component
class Configurer {

    Configurer (GenericApplicationContext context) {
        for (i = 0; ...) {
            ConnectionFactory cf = ...
            context.registerBean("cf" + i, ConnectionFactory.class, () -> cf);
            context.getBean("cf" + i); // to initialize it
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = ...
            context.registerBean("container" + i, ...);
            context.getBean("container" + i, ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 4.2.x is no longer supported; the current 4.x version is 4.3.27. 4.x won't be supported at all after this year. With older versions, you can use `((ConfigurableBeanFactory) context.getBeanFactory()).registerSingleton(...);` - but you have to do all the initialization yourself (e.g. call `afterPropertiesSet()`) - see the javadocs for `registerSingleton`.

Comment: I do not have registerBean on GenericApplicationContext (I use spring 4.2.7.RELEASE, this method is available in since 5.2). 

But I have test to add bean to ApplicationContext injected in my class. 
The DefaultMessageListenerContainer beans are injected in context, but they didn't process any message.